# C/C++, ленивые вычисления

Tags: c++, c

Являются ли вычисления условий в *C/C++* ленивыми?

То есть, есть ли разница между:

```
if ( ( a > b) && (c > d) )
{
    // ...
}
```

И:

```
if (a > b)
{
    if (c > d)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

А так же между:

```
if ( (a() > b()) && 
     (c() > d()) )
{
    // ...
}
```

И:

```
if (a() > b())
{
    if (c() > d())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

И каков порядок вычисления условий, а так же порядок вычисления функций в условии?

Comment: порядок вычисления функций в условиях не определён (у операндов `>`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, слава богу булевая операция **И** (**&&**) в стандарте ленивая. Причём порядок только слева направо.

```
Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of
the first and second operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
operand is not evaluated.
```

Comment: Но только в случае встроенных типов, если оператор переопределить, то «ленивость» теряется. Цитата, кстати, старая. В C++ нет точек следования уже 7 лет.

Comment: Хорошо, что я вовремя свалил из C++ в C)

Comment: Пора устроить забастовку: "НЕТ классам!" , "ТРЕБУЕМ только определённое ВЫЧИСЛЕНИЕ!" , "ТРЕБУЕМ, чтобы разговорная речь АССЕМБЛЕР вошла в употребление в людных местах!!!"

Comment: ух уж эти анархо-примитивисты... то уходят в леса и строят там бревенчатые хижины, то с плюсов на Си убегают...

Comment: @ixSci, нет, не теряется по крайней мере с C++17. n4659, 8/2: [...] Overloaded operators obey the rules for syntax and **evaluation order** specified in Clause 8 [...].

Comment: @wololo short-circuit свойство к evaluation order не имеет никакого отношения. Т.е. «ленивость» как была присуща только встроенным операторам, так там и осталась, т.к. её просто невозможно реализовать для перегруженных операторов.

Comment: @ixSci, да, поторопился я с написанием комментария и написал глупость. Признаю, что мой комментарий ошибочен.